# JavaScript thumbnail image gallery

Tags: javascript

Please check my code. It is almost working but whenever i click one of the thumbnails it doesnt show image.

```js
<script>
  function thumbChange(num){
    var thumb = "gata" + num + ".jpg"; 
    document.getElementById("mainImg").src = thumb;
  }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="main">
<img id="mainImg" src="biokovo.jpg" />
</div>

<ul class="thumbs">
<li onclick="thumbChange(0)"><img src="biokovo.jpg"></li>
<li onclick="thumbChange(1)"><img src="grac.jpg"></li>
<li onclick="thumbChange(2)"><img src="lokvica.jpg"></li>
<li onclick="thumbChange(3)"><img src="hike.jpg"></li>
<li onclick="thumbChange(4)"><img src="gradac.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added an answer, please check the answer and comment if you need better explaination or if you need any extra questions.. if this answer solved your issue please mark it as the right answer

Comment: Your code functions correcly to change the main image but does not change it to any of the matching 'thumbs' images. Instead it tries to load images called "gata0.jpg", "gata1.jpg", "gata2.jpg"... is that what you intend? If the main image is not being replaced with one of those, it is because images with those filenames do not exist (incidentally, the reason your snippet doesn't execute is because you have script tags inside the js panel. Delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example,
what i did, i passed the thumb as the img src.
and i pass the original size img url, as the argument of the function.

then inside the function im just passing the img url to the img tag.

```html
<img id="mainImg" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/70083/frog-macro-amphibian-green-70083.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=350&h=350&dpr=1">
  </div>
  
  <ul class="thumbs">
  <li onclick='thumbChange("https://images.pexels.com/photos/70083/frog-macro-amphibian-green-70083.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=350&h=350&dpr=1")'><img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/70083/frog-macro-amphibian-green-70083.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=100&h=100&dpr=1"></li>
  <li onclick='thumbChange("https://images.pexels.com/photos/70850/butterflies-insect-bezkregowiec-macro-70850.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=350&h=350&dpr=1")'><img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/70850/butterflies-insect-bezkregowiec-macro-70850.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=100&h=100&dpr=1"></li>
  <li onclick='thumbChange("https://images.pexels.com/photos/929773/pexels-photo-929773.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=350&h=350&dpr=1")'><img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/929773/pexels-photo-929773.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=100&h=100&dpr=1"></li>
 
  
  
    </ul>
  
  <script>
    function thumbChange(img){
       document.getElementById("mainImg").src = img;
    }
  </script>
```

im sorry for the long img urls. you can replace them with shorter ones ofcourse.